# Adding uppercase greek letters in italics to a plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, fonts

I'm preparing plots for a scientific publication. When I try to print an uppercase greek letter in italics, it uses the upright glyph instead. For instance, it works with lowercase delta but not with uppercase Delta:

```
from pylab import *

figure(figsize=(3,3))
text(1, 1,
    '$\mathit{δ}^{13}C$ $\mathit{Δ}^{14}C$',
    va='center',
    ha='center')
axis([0,2,0,2])
savefig('temp.pdf')
```

This yields the plot below. How can I print an italic version of the uppercase Delta?

After experimenting, I can actually get uppercase Greek italics if I redefine `rcParams['mathtext.bf'] = 'sans:italic'` and use `\mathbf{Δ}` instead of `\mathit{Δ}`, but if I do that I lose the ability to print Greek uppercase Greek boldface, so this displaces the problem instead of solving it.

[image]

Comment: 'Helvetica; 9.0d3e2; 2013-05-15'. I know it supports Greek because I tried in a word processor. Also, the problem is the same if I use the default matplotlib font.

Comment: The uppercase delta is printed as upright, not italics. This happens with all Greek uppercase letters.

Comment: Looking specifically at https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/tree/master/lib/matplotlib/mpl-data/fonts/pdfcorefonts, MatPlot absolutely does not use your system's version of Helvetica. It uses an `afm` derivation for Adobe core font support, which does not come with greek support at all, so I'm way more surprised mathplot even draws your text at all and I would advise asking on their issue tracker what is going on here.

Comment: I've confirmed that the issue has nothing to do with the use of a specific font. I edited the question accordingly.

Comment: nice. I would strongly recommend you also ask this on their issue tracker, though, because for all we know you found a bug. And if you get an answer there, you can just repost it here.

Comment: Thanks, I did that and if it's resolved I will report here.